# React-Router can't import components within components

Tags: node.js, reactjs, ecmascript-6, webpack, react-router

I am having a problem understanding how routes and pages should be structured using react-router, I learn the principles of react and am working off of a post placed on 24ways currently. The issue I am facing is the ability to import components.

For example I have my router setup as such:

```
// Router
export const routes = {
    path: '',
    component: appComponent,
    childRoutes: [
        {
            path: '/',
            components: {nav: navbarComponent, content: indexComponent}
        },
        {
            path: '/join',
            component: {nav: navbarComponent, content: joinComponent}
        }
    ]
};

// appComponent
import React from 'react';

export default class appComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const { nav, content } = this.props;
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="nav">
                    {nav}
                </div>
                <div className="content">
                    {content}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Is there a way that I don't have to do this an instead am able to directly import into each of my components, for example this instead:

```
// Router
export const routes = {
    path: '',
    component: appComponent,
    childRoutes: [
        {
            path: '/',
            components: indexComponent
        },
        {
            path: '/join',
            component: joinComponent
        }
    ]
};

// appComponent
import React from 'react';
import Navbar from 'Navbar';

export default class appComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Navbar />
                {this.props.children}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Have been searching all over and can't find a solution to this problem, would like to use react-router and react but it currently does not seem feasible if this is not possible. From my understanding of react the ability to build and reuse components within one another was possible.

Here is the navbar component:

```
import React from 'react';
import Navbar from 'react-bootstrap/lib/Navbar';
import Nav from 'react-bootstrap/lib/Nav';
import NavItem from 'react-bootstrap/lib/NavItem';

export default class navbarComponent extends React.Component {
    render () {
        return (
            <Navbar inverse>
                <Navbar.Header>
                    <Navbar.Brand>
                        <a href="#">React-Bootstrap</a>
                    </Navbar.Brand>
                    <Navbar.Toggle />
                </Navbar.Header>
                <Navbar.Collapse className="bs-navbar-collapse">
                    <Nav>
                        <NavItem eventKey={1} href="/">Home</NavItem>
                    </Nav>
                    <Nav pullRight>
                        <NavItem eventKey={1} href="/join">Sign Up</NavItem>
                        <NavItem eventKey={2} href="/login">Login</NavItem>
                    </Nav>
                </Navbar.Collapse>
            </Navbar>
        )
    }
}
```

The code for my server is as follows:

```
// module imports
import express from 'express';
import http from 'http';

// react imports
import React from 'react';
import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server';
import { match, RoutingContext } from 'react-router';

// route imports
import { routes } from './lib/routes';

const app = express();
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.set('views', __dirname + '/public/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    match({ routes, location: req.url }, (err, redirectLocation, props) => {
        if (err) {
            res.status(500).send(err.message);
        } else if (redirectLocation) {
            res.redirect(302, redirectLocation.pathname + redirectLocation.search);
        } else if (props) {
            const markup = renderToString(<RoutingContext {...props} />);
            res.render('index', { markup })
        } else {
            res.sendStatus(404);
        }
    });
});

const server = http.createServer(app);

server.listen(3000);
server.on('listening', () => {
    console.log('Listening on 3000');
});
```

Comment: Feel like I might be missing something here because your second example looks fine. What goes wrong when you try it?

Comment: Simply does not load the component. Ill add the component. The odd thing is that i do not receive any errors either.

Comment: @N3dst4 could it have something to do with that fact that it is universal/isomorphic?

Comment: If you're rendering on the server, maybe? Have you gone through https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/latest/docs/guides/advanced/ServerRendering.md ?

Comment: I am using an almost (if not identical setup), will post code for server.

Comment: It renders the indexComponent and joinComponent correctly.

Comment: The only thing I can see is that according to the docs, `Route` needs a `component` property, not `components`. See https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/latest/docs/Glossary.md#route . But if that doesn't help, then all I can suggest is getting a debugger in there and seeing what's what in the render method.

Comment: Thank you for the help @N3dst4, will post back if I find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using routes like the following, and I learned this via a [great tutorial from Egghead.io](https://egghead.io/series/build-your-first-react-js-application)

- **Live demo**: http://ec2-52-91-0-209.compute-1.amazonaws.com
- **Demo repo**: https://github.com/mikechabot/material-ui-hello-world

**App.js (main entry)**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Router } from 'react-router';
import routes from './config/routes.jsx';

ReactDOM.render(
    <Router>{routes}</Router>,
    document.getElementById('my-app')
);
```

**./config/routes.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import Main from '../components/Main';
import Index from '../components/Index';
import { Route, IndexRoute } from 'react-router';

export default (
    <Route path="/" component={Main}>
        <IndexRoute component={Index} />
    </Route>
)
```

**../components/Main.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';

class Main extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                Hello World. Display my children:
                {this.props.children}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Main;
```

**../components/Index.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';

class Index extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
               I'm the index Route                   
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Index ;
```

Comment: Thank you for the help but this does not work towards what I am trying to achieve, from what I can see this code still only allows one component per route without sub components in each route.

Comment: @DavidFH Not sure I understand - you can add any components you wish to the render function of Main or Index and they will be rendered accordingly.

Comment: This is the problem I am having with my initial code, the non rendering of components. Sorry for my misunderstanding. My code is create the components on the client without any of their content. Will this code allow me to work in a universal manner?

Comment: @DavidFH If we apply this example to yours, the `childRoutes` array can be replaced with `<Route path="/" component={IndexComponent}>
        <Route path="/join" component={JoinComponent} />
    </Route>`

Comment: The code example that you have given will allow me to render server side?

Comment: @DavidFH That's the idea, but I don't do isomorphic JS so I really can't say. Too much complexity for not enough gain :-) at least for my apps.

Comment: Thank you for the help, beginning to discover what I am looking for my not actually be possible without the hacky approach.